# a way to tell Webpack that `import "someFile.js"` means `import "someFile.ts"`?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is there a way to tell Webpack that anytime I have something like

```js
import "someFile.js"
```

to treat it as

```js
import "someFile.ts"
```

?

I'd like to write `import "anyFile.js"` and have it import `anyFile.ts`.

Is there a way to tell Webpack to treat one extension as some other extension (or no extension) before it goes and tries to resolve the module?

Comment: I do not know about a native WebPack function which provides this funcionality, but you could always write a loader yourselfe and swap the file ending via RegEx.

But I would rather like to know why you use file endings at all? Couldn't you just leave the file ending out? I mean webpack can also automatically resolve the file ending, so you could write `import "anyFile"`

Comment: Why do you need this? I think such behavior won't be clear for other maintainers.

Comment: @funnydman I want to find a solution that works in Electron, plain browser, and Webpack. Basically, to make TypeScript output work in native ES Modules, they recommend to place `.js` at the end of all module identifiers in TS source code which is not ideal (TypeScript issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577)). But Webpack fails to find imports when we do this. Electron does not have native modules yet, so karma-electron tests which run through `ts-node` don't work with `.js` extensions (ts-node issue: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/783)

Comment: @DustinGogoll Native ES Modules require extensions out of the box (f.e. when served from a basic static file server), unless your server handles extensions-less files. And TypeScript supports `.js` extensions in import statements, and requires this for them to appear in the output. So this works great when using `tsc`. But when making a bundle with Webpack, it fails. See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577 and https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/783. This is an unfortunate problem.

Comment: @trusktr sure, native Module Imports need a file ending. But when bundling with webpack These are not native Modules, and webpack actually uses a path resolved by default, therefor can handle Imports without specified file extensions.

Comment: @DustinGogoll True, but due to the limitation from TypeScript (that I linked to), I can't remove the extensions from the module identifiers if I want to compile to native ES Modules (not just make a bundle with Webpack). I worked around my particular issue by first compiling with TypeScript, then running Webpack on the output JS files in a second step. That doesn't answer the OP question though, and it seems Webpack doesn't have any option to do it. Maybe a plugin is the only way.